# Adding support library to android studio project

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to add v7 support for action bars to my project and followed the steps on the android dev site but still doesn't work...

In my gradle file I have

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

just like it says to do but when I try to import the class or use the resource, it isn't found.

I also downloaded the latest support library and repository in the sdk manager as well.

Am I missing a step or setting?

Comment: Did you add `/Extras/Google Repository` from the sdk?

Comment: Paste the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it.... All I needed to do was run

```
./gradlew clean build
```

in the root of my project.  Android studio wasn't updating the gradle so it didn't include the external libraries.